# Why am I getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *" here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting it for the `*` in the chunk of code

```
// click function for the "See More Scores" and "See Fewer Scores" buttons
$('.show-fewer-or-more-scores').click(function ( ) {
    var rowsNotFirst = $(this).closest('tbody').children('tr:gt(0)');
    // unravel the scores in an animated fashion
    rowsNotFirst.filter(function (idx, el) {
        setTimeout(function ( ) { $(el).toggleClass("hidden"); },
                   50 * idx);
    });
});
```

and I don't see why. I put it in [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) and was not alerted of any problems that would be causing this. Full code can be seen as commit bd4629b of https://github.com/jamkin/Snake/blob/master/SnakeGame/Scripts/game.js. You can also see the live bug [here](http://playclassicsnake.com/Play) although it may be fixed if you're accessing this thread a day or more later than it was posted.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: You have a `*/` at line 462 that is the problem not the line given above... so it is a typo... You have forgot to remove the closing chars of a multiline comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an artifact hanging around at the end of the file

[image]

Comment: Questions that are caused by a minor typographical error should be closed, not answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
var idx50 = 50*idx;
rowsNotFirst.filter(function (idx, el) {
setTimeout(function (){ $(el).toggleClass("hidden");}, idx50);
```

Comment: Your answer makes no difference